# complex SELECT across 2 tables

Tags: mysql, query, select

Given these 2 tables, how would I write a SQL query to show the teams names with its number of riders?

```
CREATE TABLE `Rider` (
  `dorsal` int NOT NULL,
  `age` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `team` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dorsal`),
  KEY `team` (`team`),
  KEY `country` (`country`),
  CONSTRAINT `rider_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`team`) REFERENCES `Team` (`id_team`),
  CONSTRAINT `rider_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`country`) REFERENCES `Country` (`id_country`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE `Team` (
  `id_team` tinyint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `director` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_team`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=23 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Comment: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2976/32281)

Comment: This is not "complex"; just join and group by.

Comment: Please show your query so far

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

In t-sql it would be

```
select t.name, count(*)
from Team t
    join Rider r on (t.id_team = r.team)
group by t.name
order by 1 --optional
```